# Ideal Rise/Run for Deck Steps for Couple Headed into Their mid-60s With Ailments

Tags: deck, stairs

I can do pretty much whatever slope etc I want for my deck steps. It's a replacement so code is not an issue. 36 inch total rise. Is a 6" rise 13" run ideal? That would be six steps from a paver walkway to a deck by the door into our kitchen. Have people done this and found it suits them? Or done closer to 7? I have arthritis and wife has a bad knee but we don't want to make the slope too low that we go too far. 13 seems good to us and have read that 6 is best.

Have people on here gone this route? Would love to get input from you.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion. We're not a discussion forum, so the question is off topic. Do some mockup testing and decide what's right for _you_.

Comment: Given age and ailments and assuming you want to stay in this house, figure out what landscaping you'll need to do to put in a ramp now, so you you don't have to move out of your house when you find that you need one, later. Include a railing you can grab, as well. Getting old sucks, but it beats the alternative.

Comment: I consider that totally non-ideal. I find walking up/down very short but deep steps to be _very_ uncomfortable and awkward. That's my _opinion_, which won't line up with other's _opinions_, which is why opinion-based questions are explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Or, if space doesn't permit a ramp, a lift. (I honestly don't see a way to put a ramp on my place, and I already have friends who are mobility-impaired.)

Answer (score 1):

There are various rules of thumb for getting comfortable stairs. One is that rise+run equals around 18”, so your plan is sound.

These would be code compliant, for what that’s worth. I don’t really know of any “replacement” clause that would allow you to do a non-compliant stair.

Edit (for those who can see it) to add a link that goes into a lot more detail about rise/run relationships… [Fine Homebuilding article](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/framing/2-rules-comfortable-stairs)

Comment: I can think of no reason for your inverse rise/run relationship rule. What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: Indeed, switch to a 12” rise and 6” run and you get the same 18” but a wildly less accessible stair. Perhaps try various stairs and see what is most comfortable, but realize a ramp may be needed eventually.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific that the rule of thumb applied only to code compliant stairs… ie, start with a rise of less than 7-1/2 or so and set the run accordingly.

Comment: I assumed code-compliance, but it still doesn't make sense to me. I'd never shorten a tread just because the rise increased.

Comment: Given code min/max, it’s really more about stretching the tread as rise decreases.